# Modify schema.rb in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am new to rails.

I want to create an Article model. So I run,

rails g model Article name:string context:string

Instead of **content** I type in **context**, Is there a way to update the schema.rb file that gets generated?

I would like the articles table to have name and content columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't focus on schema.rb -- this is just a dump of the current state of your database. Instead, what you need to do is correct the migration file. It is the migration files that actually define what tables/column will exist in production in the end so they must be correct. I'd recommend:

1. Run `ls -ltr db/migrate` -- use this to find your migration file and copy the date string. Rails uses this as the "version" of the migration. For example: "20140809165359_create_articles", the version is "20140809165359".
2. Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140809165359` (replace the version number with your own, here)
3. Now go fix your migration file (change "context" to "content")
4. Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to migrate back up.

This will fix the underlying problem and you'll notice that now, after migrating back up, your schema.rb will be fixed too.